# Explication Models and queries in django

Tags: sql, django, orm, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have question and problem at the same time, I have two models in deferents, projects like this

PROJECT: TransactionMaster.models => TransactionMaster

```
class TransactionMaster(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
       trans_status = models.BooleanField()
       trans_name = models.CharField()
```

PROJECT: TransactionDetails.models => TransactionDetail

```
from app.transactionMaster.models import TransactionMaster

class TransactionDetail(models.Model):
       transaction = models.ForeignKey(TransactionMaster, on_delete=CASCADE)
       current_status = models.IntegerField()
       transdetail_name = models.CharField()
```

how Can I do the next sql query

```
SELECT * FROM User as u inner join TransactionMaster as tm in u.id=tm.user_id inner join TransactionDetail as td in tm=td.transaction_id where tm.trans_status=td.current_status
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM TransactionMaster as tm inner join TransactionDetail as td in tm.id=td.transaction_id where tm.trans_status=td.current_status
```

I try the second query like this:

```
TransactionDetail.object.filter(TransactionMaster__id=transaction_id, trans_status=TransactionMaster__current_status)
```

Please help me with this queries, and could you answer me what can I do in models in the different project, please.

thanks for your attention
Angel Rojas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both queries, it seems that you want to get the `TransactionMaster` records that have at least one `TransactionDetail` record with a `curent_status` that is equal to the `trans_status` of the `TransactionMaster`.

In Django, that may translate to:

```
from django.db.models import F

transaction_masters = TransactionMaster.objects.filter(transactiondetail__current_status=F('trans_status'))
```

For the first query it looks as though you are interested in the users of the `TransactionMaster` records? To get the users, just extract them from the filtered `transaction_masters`.

```
users = [tm.user for tm in transaction_masters]
```